# Could someone explain to me the use of the FastRawTransactionManager class?

Tags: web3j, java

```
int pollingInterval = 3000;
FastRawTransactionManager fastRawTxMgr = new FastRawTransactionManager(web3j, credentials, new PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor(web3j, pollingInterval, 40));
```

From what I understood of the code is that those 3000 seconds are the polling intervals of the transaction generated, but I have my question for what is the number 40.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter in the FastRawTransactionManager is attempts

I think it means polling the TransactionReceipt every "pollingInterval" and retry (if polling failed) 40 times, if the retry counter reach 41 then it will throw an exception.

https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/web3j/tx/response/PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.java